# Auto proxy class for interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I have few interfaces `IFace1`, `IFace2`, etc. The interfaces have different set of methods, all the methods have different return and input params types.

I'd like to have a proxy class like

```
template<typename IFace>
class TheProxyClass : public<IFace>
{
/*...................*/
private:
  IFace * iface;
}
```

I need the class to have `IFace` methods, making them transit calling via `iface` attribute. A kind of automatic generation `IFace` methods, doing only calling corresponding ones via `iface`.

Is there way i can do it? No C++11, boost is allowed.

Comment: There is now way to do it programatically, except writing a C++ parser that reads the source and generate these classes at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Here - http://yadi.sk/d/dyOfa8yo2SbRf - is a Python script of mine, that generates impementation for given interface. Now method bodies are empty, but I think it's not so hard to modify them to insert something like that

```
"iface->" + funcName
```